# where to find out business intelligence project template for VS 2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence

When install VS 2012 RC ultimate version, no any Business Intelligence project template included. where to download those templates for VS 2012 RC?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open SSRS/SSIS/SSAS Solutions in VS 2012 itself, you have to use SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools) a VS 2012 shell that comes with the Installation of Sql Server 2012.